# Getting Code Signature Invalid when opening signed electron app

Tags: electron, electron-builder, codesign

I'm dealing with this issue for almost two weeks.
When I build my electron app in a DMG file, everything works perfect, but when I try to build the app in pkg format to upload to AppStore, I get the following error when opening:

```
EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
```

Full report: ( I don't get any idea reading this, but could you please tell me if there is anythin useful here?)

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 672ED1C3-54FF-4FC5-A724-C9BBFA324FF7
CrashReporter Key:   CEADA8D8-D266-0222-B9C5-DB0AB2503CC1
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro17,1
Process:             Foo [29494]
Path:                /Applications/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
Identifier:          com.domain.foo
Version:             1.1.4 (1.1.4)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.domain.foo [17341]

Date/Time:           2021-12-12 16:55:38.4248 -0300
Launch Time:         2021-12-12 16:55:38.3359 -0300
OS Version:          macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                       0x7ff7ffce2a2c 0x7ff7ffcdf000 + 14892


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x0000000000000000   lr: 0x0000000000000000
    sp: 0x000000030a078bb0   pc: 0x00007ff7ffce2a2c cpsr: 0x00000000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0x00000000  Address size fault

Binary Images:
    0x7ff7ffcdf000 -     0x7ff7ffd0efff  (*) <9f5d65be-d8d0-3979-bb05-e651a67e785c> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"domain","timestamp":"2021-12-12 16:55:38.00 -0300","app_version":"1.1.4","slice_uuid":"ab3cb5d1-eb3f-388f-8c63-416a00da1aaa","build_version":"1.1.4","platform":0,"bundleID":"com.domain.foo","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)","incident_id":"672ED1C3-54FF-4FC5-A724-C9BBFA324FF7","name":"domain"}
{
  "uptime" : 190000,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-12-12 16:55:38.3359 -0300",
  "procRole" : "Default",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro17,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 4762359345462,
  "coalitionID" : 17341,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.0.1",
    "build" : "21A559",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-12-12 16:55:38.4248 -0300",
  "incident" : "672ED1C3-54FF-4FC5-A724-C9BBFA324FF7",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 29494,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 4762361449260,
  "translated" : true,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "domain",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/domain.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/domain",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.1.4","CFBundleVersion":"1.1.4","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.domain.foo"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"9A6CD500-5E91-538F-B2B1-0E710ECC4FDF","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.domain.foo",
  "crashReporterKey" : "CEADA8D8-D266-0222-B9C5-DB0AB2503CC1",
  "wakeTime" : 3593,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "1E5033D3-F82F-4C6E-B325-1B31313C3DBB",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid)"},
  "termination" : {"namespace":"CODESIGNING","flags":66,"code":1},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":1348663,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":13053168560},"esr":{"value":0,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":140703125350956,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":14892,"imageIndex":0}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 140703125336064,
    "size" : 196608,
    "uuid" : "9f5d65be-d8d0-3979-bb05-e651a67e785c",
    "name" : ""
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=816K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=816K(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=21.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=21.0M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 \nStack                             8176K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       13.0M        4 \n__DATA                              80K        3 \n__DATA_CONST                        48K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                         240K        4 \n__TEXT                             624K        2 \nmapped file                        5.9G       29 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              6.0G       45 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000066
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "6194416dea7ed64a7812a429"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000322
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000174
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "61ae8d06da72d16a4beb762e"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000290
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000081
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}

Model: MacBookPro17,1, BootROM 7429.41.5, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1, Apple M1, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: Wi-Fi, wl0: Sep 13 2021 21:06:59 version 18.20.310.14.7.8.119 FWID 01-9d72ee4a
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "domain",
    "version": "1.1.4",
    "description": "",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "electron ./",
      "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=prod&& electron ./",
      "start:sbx": "set NODE_ENV=sbx&& electron ./",
      "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w",
      "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
      "clean:dist": "rimraf dist",
      "clean:win": "rimraf windows_installer",
      "build:win": "npm run clean:win&& npm run dist&& node build_installer.js",
      "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
      "dist": "npm run clean:dist&& electron-builder",
      "dist:prod": "set NODE_ENV=prod&& npm run dist",
      "create-installer-mac": "electron-installer-dmg ./dist/mac/domain.app domain --overwrite --background=./resources/background.png --icon=./resources/icons/domain.icns --out=./dist/mac/"
    },
    "build": {
      "appId": "com.domain.foo",
      "asar": true,
      "cscLink": "build/all-certs.p12",
      "cscKeyPassword": "mypassword",
      "asarUnpack": [
        "build",
        "resources"
      ],
      "mac": {
        "target": "mas"
      },
      "mas": {
        "type": "distribution",
        "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
        "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist"
      },
      "linux": {
        "target": [
          "AppImage",
          "deb"
        ]
      },
      "win": {
        "target": "nsis",
        "icon": "build/icon.ico"
      },
      "nsis": {
        "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
        "oneClick": false
      }
    },
    "author": "domain <info@domain.com>",
    "keywords": [],
    "devDependencies": {
      "appdmg": "^0.6.0",
      "electron": "^13.5.1",
      "electron-builder": "^22.11.7",
      "electron-installer-dmg": "^3.0.0",
      "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
      "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
      "electron-wix-msi": "^3.2.0",
      "exe-icon-extractor": "^1.0.8"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "auto-launch": "^5.0.5",
      "axios": "^0.24.0",
      "chokidar": "^3.4.3",
      "electron-log": "^4.3.4",
      "form-data": "^3.0.0",
      "graceful-fs": "^4.2.6",
      "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
      "keytar": "^7.4.0",
      "lodash": "^4.17.21",
      "moment": "^2.29.1",
      "nedb": "^1.8.0",
      "nedb-promises": "^4.1.0",
      "os-locale": "^5.0.0",
      "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
      "user-home": "^2.0.0"
    }
  }
```

entitlements.mas.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<string>teamid.com.domain.foo</string>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I building with `npm run dist`

If I run open -a foo.app I get:

```
-------------------------------------
```

### Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Incident Identifier: 759B0A7D-D47E-4B91-A628-E86E95B44C05
CrashReporter Key:   CEADA8D8-D266-0222-B9C5-DB0AB2503CC1
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro17,1
Process:             MyApp [3889]
Path:                /Users/USER/Documents/*/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
Identifier:          com.foo.app
Version:             1.1.10 (1.1.10)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.foo.app [1296]

Date/Time:           2022-01-04 22:14:57.5140 -0400
Launch Time:         2022-01-04 22:14:57.0231 -0400
OS Version:          macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1

Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
*dyld_process_info_create failed with 6
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯_(ツ)*/¯

EOF

---

### Full Report

{"app_name":"Foo","timestamp":"2022-01-04 22:14:59.00 -0400","app_version":"1.1.10","slice_uuid":"ab3cb5d1-eb3f-388f-8c63-416a00da1aaa","build_version":"1.1.10","platform":0,"bundleID":"com.foo.app","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)","incident_id":"759B0A7D-D47E-4B91-A628-E86E95B44C05","name":"Foo"}
{
"uptime" : 13000,
"procLaunch" : "2022-01-04 22:14:57.0231 -0400",
"procRole" : "Default",
"version" : 2,
"userID" : 501,
"deployVersion" : 210,
"modelCode" : "MacBookPro17,1",
"procStartAbsTime" : 317693807800,
"coalitionID" : 1296,
"osVersion" : {
"train" : "macOS 12.0.1",
"build" : "21A559",
"releaseType" : "User"
},
"captureTime" : "2022-01-04 22:14:57.5140 -0400",
"incident" : "759B0A7D-D47E-4B91-A628-E86E95B44C05",
"bug_type" : "309",
"pid" : 3889,
"procExitAbsTime" : 317703364649,
"translated" : true,
"cpuType" : "X86-64",
"procName" : "Foo",
"procPath" : "/Users/USER/Documents/*/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo",
"bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.1.10","CFBundleVersion":"1.1.10","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.foo.app"},
"storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"9A6CD500-5E91-538F-B2B1-0E710ECC4FDF","thirdParty":true},
"parentProc" : "launchd",
"parentPid" : 1,
"coalitionName" : "com.foo.app",
"crashReporterKey" : "CEADA8D8-D266-0222-B9C5-DB0AB2503CC1",
"wakeTime" : 160,
"sleepWakeUUID" : "FAF63016-AF61-41CB-AEA8-1FF7BED9295E",
"sip" : "enabled",
"isCorpse" : 1,
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid)"},
"termination" : {"namespace":"CODESIGNING","flags":66,"code":1},
"extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
"legacyInfo" : {
"threadHighlighted" : 0
},
"trialInfo" : {
"rollouts" : [
{
"rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
"factorPackIds" : {
"SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
},
"deploymentId" : 240000066
},
{
"rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
"factorPackIds" : {

```
  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000008
},
{
  "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
  "factorPackIds" : {
    "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "61ae8d06da72d16a4beb762e"
  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000290
},
{
  "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
  "factorPackIds" : {

  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000090
},
{
  "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
  "factorPackIds" : {
    "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "61c0d3122be4e338e11ae9e1"
  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000357
},
{
  "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
  "factorPackIds" : {

  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000196
}
```

],
"experiments" : [

]
},
"reportNotes" : [
"*dyld_process_info_create failed with 6",
"dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed",
"Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\*(ツ)_/¯"
]
}

Model: MacBookPro17,1, BootROM 7429.41.5, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC
Graphics: Apple M1, Apple M1, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: Wi-Fi, wl0: Sep 13 2021 21:06:59 version 18.20.310.14.7.8.119 FWID 01-9d72ee4a
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. If I remove the <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>, it gets build and it mostly works. But it fails when uploading that build (sandbox issue).  Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Not yet... but I-m investigating the issue right now. As I need to get it fix ASAP.

Comment: What is the output of this command: `open -a Bar.app `. Does your app launch after executing `sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - Bar.app`. (I'm also debugging a very similar problem)

Comment: @Wojtek322 I added the output of that command

Comment: @Wojtek322 were you able to fix this? I buy some time with the DMG, but I need to upload the pkg to the mac store. With the MAC version everything looks good, but with the MAS I'm still having the same issues

Comment: Sorry that I cannot be more helpful. A colleague was looking into it, but I lack the information to give a good response. We have changed the build script that signs a development build `electron-pack-dev: electron-builder -m dmg:64 mas-dev:x64` (add other parameters for your windows & linux build). One more `electron-builder` for uploading it to the store. We cannot open the build that will be uploaded to the store. What error message do you get if your prod build is signed and with what signature is it signed? @Faabass

Comment: @Wojtek322 when I run 'pkgutil --check-signature dist/mas/myapp.app' i Get 
Status: signed by a certificate trusted by macOS
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Apple Distribution: XXX Inc (XXXX)

but when I try to open the app I get

'Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))'
Is there somewhere to look for the reason of the crash?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is normal. What happens if you try to upload it via the transporter to the store? Does the transporter throw an error?

The app should not be able to be opened if you sign it with Store Signature. It will be able to be opened if you have downloaded it from the store.

Comment: @Wojtek322 (thanks for all the support!) Yes, I'm able to upload using transport, but when the Apple Reviewer try to open it crash. They just send us the screenshot and the craash report which doesn't say anything useful

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience, it was the first (and so far only) app we uploaded to the App store. It seems that the signing works correctly.  We have added a script that makes a dev build that is differently signed. It however is only executable on a very select devices (check your https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list).  I retriggered my dev script and it says that the app is being signed on the DEV build by:  'Mac Developer : App Publisher' with a certain provisioning profile. Executing this Mac on our 'test mac' should be the same version.  How can I contact you?

Comment: Hi @Wojtek322, I started a chat with you. Can you join it?

Comment: Just to know.. is there a way to test locally (with distribution cert) an app that is going to be send to the MAS, or I won't be able to open an app locally due to it will always crash and I have to send it to Review?

Comment: @Wojtek322 here is the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246650/room-for-faabass-and-wojtek322

Comment: Tested with mas-dev and also the app is crashing locally. So there is something wrong in the profile or entitlements but not sure what..

Comment: @Wojtek322 could you review the information I added in the chat? Is there anything you find weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution! But not totally sure which one it was.

What I did, was to create `quick-start` from [official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start), then following an electron build for DMG like [this one](https://medium.com/jspoint/packaging-and-distributing-electron-applications-using-electron-builder-311fc55178d9) and finally taking [this repo](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut) as an example for the entitlements and the mas setup.

After that works for the quick start app, I copy all that for the real proyect and it's works!

So the certs were ok, and I'm not sure where the issue was, but it works!

BTW: I want to thanks to @wojtek322 for all the support and the every day feedback and answers! It was amazing to have someone there helping me!