# Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid)) only after enabling sandbox in entitlements

Tags: macos, electron, code-signing, electron-builder

I'm running into an issue where the application does not want to launch when the sandbox is enabled.

I got the error in the transporter: `ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [ --list of multiple (6) execs --]"`

If I run the program with this issue, the program runs like expected. But it cannot be uploaded to the App Store. The sandbox was already partially enabled with the `webPreferences: {..., sandbox: true }`.

I managed to solve this issue by adding:
`<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key><true/>` to my entitlements file.

After a rebuild with `scripts:{..., "electron-package":"electron-build -m"}`, the application is being signed with `Developer ID Application: foo (id)` and `3rd Party Mac Developer Application: food (id)`.

When executing the following command `project-folder/dist/mas/bar.app/Contents/MacOs/bar`, it returns `zsh: killed ./bar.app/Contents/MacOS/bar` and program simply does not launch anymore

If I upload this build via the transporter, it does get successfully uploaded but will very likely fail the Apple Review.

The output from the crash report is:

```
Incident Identifier: incident-guid
CrashReporter Key:   crashreport-guid
Hardware Model:      Macmini9,1
Process:             Bar [16938]
Path:                /Users/USER/*/bar.app/Contents/MacOS/bar
Identifier:          eu.comany.bar
Version:             0.8.4 (0.8.4)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      zsh [722]
Coalition:           com.apple.Terminal [845]
Responsible Process: Terminal [720]

Date/Time:           2021-12-22 14:23:42.0103 +0100
Launch Time:         2021-12-22 14:23:41.8950 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 12.1 (21C52)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1

Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EOF
```

My entitlements.mac.plist are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>      
      <string>id.eu.company.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.microphone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

my info.plist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>CopySelected.workflow</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>Bar by Foo</string>
    <key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSBackgroundColorName</key>
            <string>background</string>
            <key>NSIconName</key>
            <string>NSActionTemplate</string>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>CopySelected</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>runWorkflowAsService</string>
            <key>NSSendTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.utf8-plain-text</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My package.json contains:

```
 "mac": {
      "icon": "icons/icon.icns",
      "category": "public.app-category.xxxxxxxx",
      "entitlements": "entitlements.mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "entitlements.mac.plist",
      "provisioningProfile": "provisioning/bar.provisionprofile",
      "extraResources": [
        "electron/bin/**/*"
      ],
      "target": [
        "mas"
      ],
      "binaries": [],
      "extendInfo": {
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Bar requires microphone access."
      }
    },
```

`security find-identity -vp codesigning` returns (terminal command):

```
Developer ID application: xx (yy)
3rd Party Mac developer Application: xx (yy)
Apple Development: person (zz) //not used
Apple Distribution: xx (yy) //not used
4 valid identities found
```

My electron-build output:

```
> bar@0.8.4 preelectron-pack

> npm run build-react



> bar@0.8.4 build-react

> cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=PROD react-scripts build


Creating an optimized production build...


> bar@0.8.4 electron-pack

> electron-builder -m "mas"


  • electron-builder  version=22.10.5 os=21.2.0

  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)

  • writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml

  • packaging       platform=mas arch=arm64 electron=13.2.0 appOutDir=dist/mas-arm64

  • Unpacking electron zip  zipPath=undefined

  • signing         file=dist/mas/Bar.app identityName=Developer ID Application: xxxxxxxx (yyyyyyy) identityHash=71103A11A7D2CD51ACD921809C7358B6E28B8ACD provisioningProfile=certs/Bar.provisionprofile

  • signing         file=dist/mas/Bar.app identityName=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: xxxxxxxxxxxx (yyyyyyyyy) identityHash=4EF2E5C611EB01CA290E651B55BEBC2424589C3C provisioningProfile=certs/Bar.provisionprofile
```

codesign -dvvv dist/mas/Bar.app

```
>>> codesign -dvvv dist/mas/Bar.app

Executable=/path_to_bar/bar/dist/mas/Bar.app/Contents/MacOS/Bar

Identifier=eu.company.bar

Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)

CodeDirectory v=20400 size=3093 flags=0x0(none) hashes=86+7 location=embedded

Hash type=sha256 size=32

CandidateCDHash sha1=created-sha1-hash

CandidateCDHashFull sha1=created-sha1-hash

CandidateCDHash sha256=created-sha256-hash

CandidateCDHashFull sha256=created-sha256-hash

Hash choices=sha1,sha256

CMSDigest=created-cmsdigest

CMSDigestType=2

CDHash=created-cdhash

Signature size=9183

Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: xxx (yyy)

Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

Authority=Apple Root CA

Timestamp=29 Dec 2021 at 13:39:08

Info.plist entries=31

TeamIdentifier=yyy (same id as the yyy in certificate)

Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=16

Internal requirements count=1 size=208
```

pkgutil --check-signature dist/mas/Bar-0.8.4.pkg

```
Package "Bar-0.8.4.pkg":

   Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple (Development)

   Certificate Chain:

    1. 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: xxx (yyy)

       Expires: 2022-11-30 14:04:56 +0000

       SHA256 Fingerprint:

           4F 54 4F 4B 21 A4 39 95 CD 62 65 AD C8 F7 7E DD AC 77 9D 5F 39 AB 

           99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11 00

       ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    2. Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

       Expires: 2030-02-20 00:00:00 +0000

       SHA256 Fingerprint:

           DC F2 18 78 C7 7F 41 98 E4 B4 61 4F 03 D6 96 D8 9C 66 C6 60 08 D4 

           24 4E 1B 99 16 1A AC 91 60 1F

       ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    3. Apple Root CA

       Expires: 2035-02-09 21:40:36 +0000

       SHA256 Fingerprint:

           B0 B1 73 0E CB C7 FF 45 05 14 2C 49 F1 29 5E 6E DA 6B CA ED 7E 2C 

           68 C5 BE 91 B5 A1 10 01 F0 24
```

It is very possible that I did one of the following things wrong.
I tried:

- Reimplement certificates
- Redid provisiningprofile
- Sandbox way according to Electron
- Sandbox way according to Apple Developer docs
- Sign application after build
- Remove certain certificates
- Sign with different certificates (this was unsuccessful)
- Created certfs via Xcode
- Tried to import the project in xcode and failed
- Nearly all proposed solutions from the first page on Google. There was a major lack of relevant posts.
- ...

I'm probably forgetting a few

I am unable to find any solutions that solve this for the past week. If you need any more troubleshoot information, please let me know?

Comment: Gotta love it when the computer throws up its own hands.. `corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: are you misspelling the paths in package.json?   You state `"entitlements": "entitlements.mas.plist",` but also called the file `entitlements.ma` **c** `.plist`

Comment: Good catch but that is a typo only in the SO post. Sorry, I'll correct it. It was correctly referred in the project.

Comment: Other typos,, the path to the binary executable.. Bar.app/Contents/MacOS/Bar . There are three subtly differrent versions.   Also, "mas" package is trying to be built, but you define "mac".

Comment: The 'bar' is a placeholder but I've seen only that it has inconsistent capitalization. The package gets build to the `/dist/mas/` directory and it signed with `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` certificate. So it looks like it indeed gets build for mas.

Comment: I've added the output for `pkgutil --check-signature` and `codesign -dvvv`

Comment: Usually with an `.app` you launch it with `open -a Bar`…

Comment: Executing `open -a Bar.app` in the correct directory outputs: 

`The application /path_to_project/dist/mas/Bar.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000006629d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240562/discussion-between-richard-barber-and-wojtek322).

Comment: Did you make it works? I have a similar post to this, but I'm still facing the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327436/getting-code-signature-invalid-when-opening-signed-electron-app?noredirect=1#comment124533947_70327436

Comment: Nope, I did not manage to solve my issue yet. Your issue looks slightly different but I do think the same solution will work... if we find one.

Answer (score 3):

A solution from [this mulesoft support thread](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005mxy8USAQ/anypoint-studio-7120-is-crashing-at-launch-on-macos-1231just-after-a-few-launch-that-had-no-problems-now-i-cant-launch-anypointstudio-anymore-because-it-always-crashes-with-this-error-that-youll-find-in-the-detailcan-anyone-help-me-please-?t=1689618344284) worked for me when I ran into the 'Code Signature Invalid' error. Note that I did not encounter this when enabling the sandbox, it just started happening randomly to me:

Force the signature via the command line:

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/AnypointStudio.app
```

Comment: Terrific! works perfect for me for SpringBoot Tool suite on Imac Macos Ventura. Thanks a lot!